# XCB: xcb_wait_for_event does not catch event generated by application

Tags: c++, xcb

I have a small xcb based library for GUI programming. One of its methods forces redrawing of specified rectangle in window area. It creates Expose event and sends it to a window:

```
void GWindow::redrawRectangle(const I2Rectangle& r) {
    xcb_rectangle_t rect;
    rect.x = (short) r.left(); rect.y = (short) r.top();
    rect.width = (unsigned short) r.width(); 
    rect.height = (unsigned short) r.height();
    xcb_set_clip_rectangles(m_Connection, XCB_CLIP_ORDERING_UNSORTED,
                        m_GC, 0, 0, 1, &rect);

    xcb_expose_event_t *e = (xcb_expose_event_t*)malloc(sizeof(xcb_expose_event_t));
    memset(e, 0, sizeof(xcb_expose_event_t));
    e->response_type = XCB_EXPOSE;
    e->window = m_Window;
    e->x = r.left();
    e->y = r.top();
    e->width = r.width();
    e->height = r.height();
    e->count = 0;
    xcb_send_event(m_Connection, 0, m_Window, XCB_EVENT_MASK_EXPOSURE, (char*)e);
    xcb_flush(m_Connection);
}
```

Here `r` is a rectangle with vertices which have integer coordinates.

Also, I have event loop which uses `xcb_wait_for_event` to get an event and dispatches it to an appropriate callback function.

So, when I call `redrawRectangle` method, nothing happens on screen. I have investigated and have found out that event generarated by the function doesn't get into event loop. But xscope says that X server gets request for the event and emits it. What's wrong with it?

**UPD 1** Window event mask is set via `xcb_set_window_attributes`. The mask is `XCB_EVENT_MASK_EXPOSURE | XCB_EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_PRESS | XCB_EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_RELEASE | XCB_EVENT_MASK_KEY_PRESS | XCB_EVENT_MASK_POINTER_MOTION | XCB_EVENT_MASK_STRUCTURE_NOTIFY | XCB_EVENT_MASK_SUBSTRUCTURE_NOTIFY | XCB_EVENT_MASK_FOCUS_CHANGE`

**UPD 2** ClientMessage isn't catched by `xcb_wait_for_event` too.

Comment: Doesn't `xscope` intercept all traffic between the server and your application? So, if `xscope` shows the event, then it must reach your application.

Comment: Also, why do you need to send yourself an expose event? Couldn't you just redraw the affected rectangle directly?

Comment: @UliSchlachter there is some code that is executed before and after passing the event to an app. This code sets clip rectangle. Of course, I can add this logic to ```GWindow::redraw```, but I am still interested in resolving original problem. I suppose that it is caused by misunderstanding something in xcb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble was in examining event type. To extract type, one should use `event->response_type & ~0x80`, not just `event->response_type`